# Gradle: testDependents and testNeeded

Tags: groovy, gradle

With the gradle java plugin you get the following tasks which are very neat:

buildDependents
buildNeeded

I would like to have similar tasks for running tests only.

testDependents - runs the unit tests for this project and all projects that depend on it.
testNeeded - runs the unit tests for this and all projects it depends on.

Can I somehow create such custom tasks in gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the following answer from the gradle forums.

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin:'java'
    task testDependents{
        dependsOn (configurations.testRuntime.getTaskDependencyFromProjectDependency(false, "testDependents"))
        dependsOn test
    }
    task testNeeded{
        dependsOn (configurations.testRuntime.getTaskDependencyFromProjectDependency(true, "testNeeded"))
       dependsOn test
    }
}
```